# Get Variables with spaces in Shell

Tags: shell, unix

I have this variable in a config file:

```
DIR_CNF="C:/Documents and Settings/Administrador/Escritorio/PRUEBA/CNF"         ;export DIR_CNF #DIRECTORIO CONFIG
```

but when I rescued to create a directory I get this:

```
mkdir: directory "C:/Documents": You can not create a file that already exists.
```

Please help me.

Comment: I think the problem might be on the line where you're calling `mkdir`. You will need to put double quotes around the variable there.

Comment: It's working, thanks